# CKEditor scripts loads twice

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I have two CKEditor controls in my page. I am using

```
 CKEDITOR.replace(Textarea);
```

While running all the scripts related to CKEditor are loading twice. Is this a normal scenario??

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854455/appendchild-executing-twice-in-ckeditor

Comment: My Code : $(function () {CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtRR.ClientID %>', { toolbar: 'MyToolbar' }, { removePlugins: 'elementspath' });CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtBUDescription.ClientID %>', { toolbar: 'MyToolbar' }, { removePlugins: 'elementspath' });
CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;});