# Multiple CKEditor 5 editors in one form with Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Using ckeditor 5, I tried to add a button to write a specific text inside ckeditor5. I have a wysiwyg editor for each language. But I do not know why, the ckeditor instance created appears twice for each language.

below my code

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
 ?>
<div class="col-md-12" id="categoriesDescription<?php echo $languages[$i]['id']; ?>">
   <?php
     $name = 'categories_description[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']';
     $ckeditor_id = $Wysiwyg::getWysiwygId($name);

     echo $Wysiwyg::textAreaCkeditor($name, 'soft', '750', '300', (isset($categories_description[$languages[$i]['id']]) ? str_replace('& ', '&amp; ', trim($categories_description[$languages[$i]['id']])) : $CLICSHOPPING_CategoriesAdmin->getCategoryDescription($cInfo->categories_id, $languages[$i]['id'])), 'id="' . $ckeditor_id . '"');
                      ?>
                      </div>
<?php
echo $this->getCategoriesDescription(......);
}
?>
```

my javascript function to appear the button

```
public static function getCategoriesDescription(string $content, string $urlMultilanguage, string $translate_language, string $question, string $categories_name, string $url)
    {
      $script = "
<script defer>
  const editors = {}; // Objet pour stocker les instances CKEditor
  let isFirst = true; // Indicateur pour la première itération de la boucle

  $(document).ready(function() {
    let button = '{$content}';

    $('[id^=\"categoriesDescription\"]').each(function(index) {
      let textareaId = $(this).find('textarea').attr('id');
      let regex = /(\d+)/g;
      let idcategoriesDescription = regex.exec(textareaId)[0];

      let language_id = parseInt(idcategoriesDescription);
      let newButton = $(button).attr({
        'data-index': index,
        'data-editor-id': 'categories_description' + idcategoriesDescription
      });

      // Envoi d'une requête AJAX pour récupérer le nom de la langue
      let self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: '{$urlMultilanguage}',
        data: {id: language_id},
        success: function(language_name) {
          let questionResponse = '{$translate_language}' + ' ' + language_name + ' : ' + '{$question}' + ' ' + '{$categories_name}';

          newButton.click(function() {
            let message = questionResponse;
            let engine = $('#engine').val();
            let editorId = $(this).data('editor-id');
            let editor = editors[editorId];

            if (editor) {
              $.ajax({
                url: '{$url}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {message: message, engine: engine},
                success: function(data) {
                  editor.setData(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
              });
            } else {
              console.error('Éditeur introuvable : ' + editorId);
            }
          });

          if (newButton) {
            $(self).append(newButton);



// I think the pb come here I think

            //Create an instance for every language
            let editorId = 'categories_description' + idcategoriesDescription;
            if (!editors[editorId]) {
              ClassicEditor
                .create(document.getElementById(editorId))
                .then(editor => {
                  editors[editorId] = editor;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
                });
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
";

      return $script;
    }
?>
```

below an image allow you to see what's happen.
The text is include inside the first wysiwyg but the true wysiwyg is the second !!!!!

link to see the image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UDNi.png

Thank you for you help, I tried many way but I have no idea what's happen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I don't have a straight forward answer for your question, but there is quite some Q&A on site already that is about it. Perhaps some of it has an answer that already speaks to you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23854455/367456 is just one of them, if I get it right they all circulate about the initialization of the component running again and the solution then is to prevent that.